# Limit number suggestions display in typeahead.js

Tags: typeahead.js

As the title, I want to ask: "Is it possible to limit the suggestions displayed in typeahead?"

For example, I have 3 datasets, each dataset has 10000 results (from the query). And a subject started with character `t` is about 3000 results or may be more.

What will happened if I type `t` in the input ? 3000 result display or ... ?

Or is there any way to force user type specific characters then display suggestions ? (Like I must type `tem`, single character like `t` will not be accpeted)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should use a combination of `limit` and `minLength`. `limit` is the max number of suggestions that will be displayed for a given query (defaults to `5`) and `minLength` is the minimum number of characters a query needs before suggestions start to get rendered (defaults to `0`).

Comment: Actually default value for minLength is 1(at least now)
https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/src/typeahead/typeahead.js

Comment: this is not valid for the latest. if you are using bloodhound, limit is an option on bloodhound, while minLength is an option on typeahead

Comment: I needed to add the 'items' option instead of 'limit'. I have  bootstrap3-typeahead.js v3.1.0

Answer (score 8):

The default limit is 5, you can set the "limit" option to what you want.

[Read the doc ;-)](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/bloodhound.md)

Answer (score 0):

For limiting suggestions
Use "items: x", where x will be the number of suggestion to be displayed after typing some character.
e.g, if items: 5, then 5 suggestions will be shown at max for whatever you typed.